# Generating a random number from date in a reproducive manner in PHP

Tags: php, function, random

I have been struggling with a problem for a while now.

Namely I need to generate a number in range 1 - 50 using a date. What I mean is if I run a some piece of code withing a specific date, it should produce me the same number for that day. If the date changes it should produce me a different number in defined range and preferably that does not show pattern with numbers generated in previous dates (constantly rising for example). I believe it can't be done with some mathematical linear function since the graph of that function would always produce me a pattern how the numbers are changing in time. Perhaps there is some function that is used in cryptography that would help?

Answer (score 0):

seed your random generator via [srand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php)

If the input number should does not change for the day then your random returns will be predictable for that day.

You can use the number of days since 1970, or the day of the month as a seed value

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hashing algorithm on your date convert it to a number and define an upper bound using modulo e.g.:

```
$yournumber = hexdec( sha1($date) ) % 50;
```